# In While loop python, the test condition variable value is not updating - AWS - Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, while-loop, metrics

Hi I'm a very new python programmer and I have encountered a problem with quota query code.

```
def get_metric_statistics(instance_args):
CMD  = (**querying the quota***)
print (CMD)
output = run_command_str(command=CMD, shell_command=True)
applied_quota_value = json.loads(output)
max_quota_metric = applied_quota_value ['Quota']['Value']
print ("max_quota:", max_quota_metric)

CMD1 = (***querying metric**)
print (CMD1)
output1 = run_command_str(command=CMD1, shell_command=True)
print ("output:", output1)
utilized_quota_value = json.loads(output1)
used_quota_metric = utilized_quota_value ['Datapoints'][0]['Maximum']
print ("used:", used_quota_metric)
available_quota = max_quota_metric - used_quota_metric
instance_args["no_of_vcpu"] = some value

while available_quota < instance_args["no_of_vcpu"]:
    print ("Waiting for vcpu to be available")
    time.sleep(30)
else:
    print ("available quota is greater than requested vcpu, continues to launch the instance")
aws_metric_data = get_metric_statistics(instance_args)
print(aws_metric_data)
```

so here im trying to check the condition and print the subsequent statements, But when the variable with the value in the condition enters the loop, it checks the condition is true and the true condition is looping over even after the variable has been updated by a different value. The variable in the condition is basically not getting updated. Not sure how to get that piece of code  which does the update inside the loop.

Comment: What variable are you updating? The body of that while loop will just print and then sleep over and over. No variable is being updating in it

Comment: Please make sure that indentation is preserved. There's probably some indent missing after `def get_metric_statistics`.

Comment: @testfile yes the variable is not getting updated. My question is how to bring in the updated variables in the condition inside the loop.

Comment: @Light605 see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70620357/6014330 on how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is not being updated in the while loop. I've moved your calculations into a seperate function. When the while loop runs after the sleep the available quota will be recalculated

```
def calc_available_quota():
    CMD  = (**querying the quota***)
    print (CMD)
    output = run_command_str(command=CMD, shell_command=True)
    applied_quota_value = json.loads(output)
    max_quota_metric = applied_quota_value ['Quota']['Value']
    print ("max_quota:", max_quota_metric)

    CMD1 = (***querying metric**)
    print (CMD1)
    output1 = run_command_str(command=CMD1, shell_command=True)
    print ("output:", output1)
    utilized_quota_value = json.loads(output1)
    used_quota_metric = utilized_quota_value ['Datapoints'][0]['Maximum']
    print ("used:", used_quota_metric)
    return max_quota_metric - used_quota_metric


def get_metric_statistics(instance_args):
    instance_args["no_of_vcpu"] = some_value
    available_quota = calc_available_quota()

    while available_quota < instance_args["no_of_vcpu"]:
        print ("Waiting for vcpu to be available")
        time.sleep(30)
        available_quota = calc_available_quota()
    else:
        print ("available quota is greater than requested vcpu, continues to launch the instance")
    aws_metric_data = get_metric_statistics(instance_args)
    print(aws_metric_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
while available_quota < instance_args["no_of_vcpu"]:
    print ("Waiting for vcpu to be available")
    time.sleep(30)
else:
    print ("available quota is greater than requested vcpu, continues to launch the instance")
```

The while loop is entered with two values, which are compared. But since the values are not being updated within the loop, the while loop will go around forever. You need to continually check the values within the loop as well, using the code which you used to calculate the values in the first place.

Something like this:

```
while available_quota < instance_args["no_of_vcpu"]:
    print ("Waiting for vcpu to be available")
    time.sleep(30)
    output1 = run_command_str(command=CMD1, shell_command=True)
    print ("output:", output1)
    utilized_quota_value = json.loads(output1)
    used_quota_metric = utilized_quota_value ['Datapoints'][0]['Maximum']
    print ("used:", used_quota_metric)
    available_quota = max_quota_metric - used_quota_metric
    instance_args["no_of_vcpu"] = some value
else:
    print ("available quota is greater than requested vcpu, continues to launch the instance")
```

Although since the additional part is a standalone working component, I might put it into a function.

```
 def getStatus():
     output1 = run_command_str(command=CMD1, shell_command=True)
     print ("output:", output1)
     utilized_quota_value = json.loads(output1)
     used_quota_metric = utilized_quota_value ['Datapoints'][0]['Maximum']
     print ("used:", used_quota_metric)
     available_quota = max_quota_metric - used_quota_metric
     instance_args["no_of_vcpu"] = some value

     return available_quota, instance_args["no_of_vcpu"]
```

Then:

```
while available_quota < instance_args["no_of_vcpu"]:
    print ("Waiting for vcpu to be available")
    time.sleep(30)
    available_quota,instance_args["no_of_vcpu"]=getStatus()
else:
    print ("available quota is greater than requested vcpu, continues to launch the instance")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i have to bring in the updated variables as well inside the code but im not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Light605: simply, additionally evaluate `available_quota` and `instance_args` inside the while loop. You need to evaluate them before you enter the while loop, but you also need to evaluate them for the next time around the loop. I would revaluate them after the sleep, the sleep is ensure that you're not asking the questions too often. I have edited the answer to show this.